# Are visits to UK and Ireland included in the Schengen 90/180 days rule?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

I am coming up to 90 days in the EU (Italy, Ireland and the UK):

Italy is part of the Schengen zone (there spent 30 days)
Ireland is NOT Schengen (30 days)
UK is also NOT Schengen (30 days)

So my 90 of 180 days in the EU is just about to be up and I do not have a visa (US travelers are not required to have a visa for 90 day stays abroad in EU - only a passport).

I want to go to France next (part of the Schengen zone), would I have still 60 days left to do so, or would my total European stay have eaten up all of my 90 days?

Comment: For visa the EU has no influence, it is Schengen you have to consider now, so you basically still have 60 days left. Do check out the Schengen day counter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Will check that out now... great news :)

Answer (score 10):

Schengen and the EU have some countries in common, but are not exactly the same set of countries. While they mostly overlap, there are Schengen countries which are not in the EU (namely, Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Iceland), and EU countries which are not in Schengen (namely, the UK, Ireland, Romania, Bulgaria, Croatia and Cyprus).

The 90/180 rule applies only to time spent in Schengen area countries, even if not in the EU. It does not apply to time spent outside Schengen, even if it is in an EU member state.

Schengen members can always be confirmed at the [Migration and Home Affairs](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm) site.

The official Schengen [Calculator of travel days remaining under a Schengen short-stay visa](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) can be used reliably in cases of 90/180 doubt.

Comment: (+1) Norway and Iceland are part of the Schengen area while not being EU members as well. Unlike Switzerland they are however EEA members. Liechtenstein is also associated with the Schengen area (but does not issue visa).

Answer (score 7):

While Michael Hampton's answer is correct, I think a simpler approach is indicated.

Your question is based on the incorrect premise that your stay is limited to 90 days out of 180 in the EU.  It isn't.  That rule applies *to the Schengen countries.*  Ireland and the UK have separate limits.  Therefore:

> I want to go to France next.  Would I have still 60 days left to do so?

Yes.